# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) for google clone react app

Tags: reactjs, google-search-api, rapidapi

i integrated my react app with google search api from rapidapi.com,everything is working except the image result (nothing is shown in image result)and when checked the console of chrome its showing the following error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

case '/images':
return (

{results?.image_results?.map(({ image, link: { href, title } }, index) => (


{title}

))}

);

Answer (score 0):

use **'/image'** instead of **'/images'** wherever necessary because rapidAPI supports path of **'/image'** and not **'/images'** in the url